# Keep legend colors the same across several plots

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am working on a dataset for which I calculate multiple statistics. For each of the stats I want to create a stacked bar plot. However, the color of the legends changes from plot to plot, because obviously they are calculate again from scratch for every plot. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "X": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 5,
        "Y": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
        "v": np.random.random(8),
    }
).set_index(["X", "Y"])

ax = df1.unstack().loc[:, "v"].plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(5, 2))
ax.legend(loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.55), ncol=5)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "X": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 4,
        "Y": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "e"],
        "v": np.random.random(7),
    }
).set_index(["X", "Y"])
ax = df2.unstack().loc[:, "v"].plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(5, 2))
ax.legend(loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -.55), ncol=5)
```

The result are two plots like this:

[image]

As one can see, "e" has different colors in the two plots. Any suggestion how I can harmonize the colors across several plots?

Comment: The plots you create are not seaborn plots, so this question is pretty misleading. Because if you used seaborn it would be easier.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest - thank you very much, I had used seaborn earlier for this part of code, so I must have still had it in my mind when I was asking the question - I changed the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict to map the name of each Serie to a color. Then assign that color when plotting:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "X": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 5,
        "Y": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
        "v": np.random.random(8),
    }
).set_index(["X", "Y"])
colores = {'a': 'green', 'b': 'red', 'c': 'orange', 'd': 'blue', 'e': 'brown'}
df_plot1 = df1.unstack()["v"]
ax = df_plot1.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(5, 2), color=df_plot1.columns.map(colores))
ax.legend(loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.55), ncol=5)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "X": ["A"] * 3 + ["B"] * 4,
        "Y": ["a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "e"],
        "v": np.random.random(7),
    }
).set_index(["X", "Y"])

df_plot2 = df2.unstack()["v"]
ax = df_plot2.plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, figsize=(5, 2), color=df_plot2.columns.map(colores))
ax.legend(loc="lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -.55), ncol=5)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Awesome, I did not know about this - thank you very much!